# How do I stop "PDF, JSON, and Dockerfiles" from opening on download button in the browser

Tags: json, reactjs, pdf, redux

I have a React Application, that has a download button. The download button is there to allow people to download different files. The file types are PDF, JSON, DOCKERFILE, and ZIP.

The browser automatically opens the the pdf and json files. I want it to stop opening them. Here is the code for that:

```
if (nextProps.action == DOWNLOAD_FILE_SUCCESS) {

    setTimeout(() => {
            window.location.href = this.props.url;
    }, 100);
}
```

My question is how do I stop them from opening and just downloading them.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [download.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/downloadjs) npm package for this.
It can trigger a file download from JavaScript instead of opening it directly in the browser

Comment: Yeah, I will try it, but the documentation isn't very good, and I am a beginner. On top of that, I don't want to put an entire dependency just for that. Do you know, of a native way in ES6 JavaScript, that we can achieve that? Thanks for your answer..